# How to add/use GStreamer binary library with Qt C++ on Android?

Tags: android, c++, qt, gstreamer, qmake

I am attempting to use Gstreamer library on multiple platforms with my Qt project (for audio only). I already have it working on macOS with the binary files [available online](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/) by just adding the framework to my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -F$$PWD/macOS/libs/ -framework GStreamer
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/macOS/libs/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/macOS/libs/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/include
```

But now I want to use the binaries available at the same page for android. But because it is not "bundled" in a framework like on OS X I can't add it as easily. Furthermore the [official explanations](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/for-android-development.html?gi-language=c) are made for a gradle build (which I don't know anything and don't use in Qt creator) and for use in Java. But, because I want to directly use the C API in Qt C++ I don't need JNI, and would like to directly use the library in my app like on OSX.

Thus, I tried to add the library like I would do it on any other linux, but recursively, since there is a multitude of library and header folders:

```
    contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH,arm64-v8a) {
        ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
    
        GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_FILES = $$files($$PWD/android/libs/gstreamer/arm64/include/*, true)
        for(FILE, GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_FILES) {
            BASEDIR = $$dirname(FILE)
            if(!contains(INCLUDEPATH, $$BASEDIR)){
                INCLUDEPATH += $$BASEDIR
            }
        }
    
        GSTREAMER_DEPEND_FILES = $$files($$PWD/android/libs/gstreamer/arm64/include/*, true)
        for(FILE, GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_FILES) {
            BASEDIR_DEP = $$dirname(FILE)
            if(!contains(DEPENDPATH, $$BASEDIR_DEP)){
                DEPENDPATH += $$BASEDIR_DEP
            }
        }
    
        GSTREAMER_LIB_FILES = $$files($$PWD/android/libs/gstreamer/arm64/lib/*.a, true)
        for(FILE, GSTREAMER_LIB_FILES) {
            BASENAME = $$basename(FILE)
            LIBS += -l$$replace(BASENAME,\.a,)
        }
    }
```

But when I try the include

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
```

, it doesn't work and output 37 errors on unknown members of the global namespace related to time management like :

```
/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ctime:70:9: error: no member named 'asctime' in the global namespace
using ::asctime;
      ~~^
```

I really don't know how to use gstreamer and bundle it for android from the available official binaries and don't want to use any wrapper like qt-gstreamer (which isn't maintained by the way) or JNI.

Thanks for any help or input !